# How do I embed this video from Animoto using JWplayer?

Tags: video, embed, jwplayer

How do I embed this video from Animoto using JWplayer?

The video needs to be embedded on a SharePoint 2013 site.

http://animoto.com/play/GGu6DpbrnW7EEENfW7S0NQ

Answer (score 1):

We only officially support YouTube as a 3rd party source - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support